# Python Bubble sort recursion. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, bubble-sort

I am doing a recursion assignment for class. I understand how to use the formula, but I believe I am doing something wrong here along the lines of printing the dictionary out correctly. Can someone please help me figure out how to get the right output?

```
[('4213', 'STEM Center', 0), ('4201', 'Foundations Lab', 1), ('4204', 'CS Lab', 2), ('4218', 'Workshop Room', 3), ('4205', 'Tiled Room', 4), ('Out', 'Outside', 5)]
[('4201', 'Foundations Lab', 1), ('4204', 'CS Lab', 2), ('4205', 'Tiled Room', 4), ('4213', 'STEM Center', 0), ('4218', 'Workshop Room', 3), ('Out', 'Outside', 5)]
[('4204', 'CS Lab', 2), ('4201', 'Foundations Lab', 1), ('Out', 'Outside', 5), ('4213', 'STEM Center', 0), ('4205', 'Tiled Room', 4), ('4218', 'Workshop Room', 3)]
[('4204', 'CS Lab', 2), ('4201', 'Foundations Lab', 1), ('Out', 'Outside', 5), ('4213', 'STEM Center', 0), ('4205', 'Tiled Room', 4), ('4218', 'Workshop Room', 3)]
```

Instead I am getting:

```
[('4213', 'STEM Center', 0), ('4218', 'Workshop Room', 3), ('4201', 'Foundations Lab', 1), ('4205', 'Tiled Room', 4), ('4204', 'CS Lab', 2), ('out', 'Outside', 5)]
```

None
None

---

I have gotten this far with figuring this out.

```
def recursiveSort(sensor_list,n,t): #Recursive Sort
if n == 0:
    return sensor_list
    for i in range(n-1):
        if sensor_list[i][t] > sensor_list[i + 1][t]:
        temp = sensor_list[i]
        sensor_list[i] =sensor_list[i + 1]
        sensor_list[i + 1] = temp

return recursiveSort(sensor_list,n - 1,t)

Dict = {'4213' : ('STEM Center', 0),
'4201' : ('Foundations Lab', 1),
'4204' : ('CS Lab', 2),
'4218' : ('Workshop Room', 3),
'4205' : ('Tiled Room', 4),
'out' :  ('Outside', 5),
}

sensor_list=[]

[ sensor_list.append((key,Dict[key][0],Dict[key][1])) for key in Dict ] #Adding values to a dictionary into a tuple using list comprehension

print sensor_list


print recursiveSort(sensor_list,len(sensor_list),0)

print recursiveSort(sensor_list,len(sensor_list),1)

print sensor_list
```

Comment: What is the `t` parameter supposed to be doing? Also, can you fix your indents? It makes it hard to read your code.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. And your question is tagged python3, but you clearly use python2 style print statements.

Comment: At the moment, `recursiveSort` isn't doing anything because you've got the `for` loop following a `return` statement, so it'll never be called. Either you have made some errors in pasting your code here or you've got errors in your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code with the proper indentation like below and got the right output.

```
def recursiveSort(sensor_list,n,t): #Recursive Sort
    if n == 0:
        return sensor_list
    for i in range(n-1):
        if sensor_list[i][t] > sensor_list[i + 1][t]:
            temp = sensor_list[i]
            sensor_list[i] =sensor_list[i + 1]
            sensor_list[i + 1] = temp

    return recursiveSort(sensor_list,n - 1,t)

Dict = {'4213' : ('STEM Center', 0),
'4201' : ('Foundations Lab', 1),
'4204' : ('CS Lab', 2),
'4218' : ('Workshop Room', 3),
'4205' : ('Tiled Room', 4),
'out' :  ('Outside', 5),
}

sensor_list=[]

[sensor_list.append((key,Dict[key][0],Dict[key][1])) for key in Dict ] #Adding values to a dictionary into a tuple using list comprehension

print sensor_list


print recursiveSort(sensor_list,len(sensor_list),0)

print recursiveSort(sensor_list,len(sensor_list),1)

print sensor_list
```

According to the output you have got, I think the error is with the incorrect indentation of the for loop. Most probably it is looks like this.

```
if n == 0:
    return sensor_list
    for i in range(n-1):
        if sensor_list[i][t] > sensor_list[i + 1][t]:
            temp = sensor_list[i]
            sensor_list[i] =sensor_list[i + 1]
            sensor_list[i + 1] = temp
```

The for loop is not getting executed at all because,

- when n == 0, because the return statement is before the loop
- when n != 0, because the the for loop part is inside the if block.

And probably your `return recursiveSort(sensor_list,n - 1,t)` statement is also out of indent.

Comment: Thank you a bunch for fixing this error for me. I'm quite new to python so I'm not sure how to fix certain things.

Comment: Also would you happen to know how to order the list recursively by the second tuple number as in 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: print recursiveSort(sensor_list,len(sensor_list),2)

Answer (score 0):

```
def recursiveSort(sensor_list,n,t): #Recursive Sort
if (n == 0):

    return sensor_list
else:
    for i in range(n-1):
        if sensor_list[i][t] > sensor_list[i + 1][t]:
            temp = sensor_list[i]
            sensor_list[i] =sensor_list[i + 1]
            sensor_list[i + 1] = temp


    return recursiveSort(sensor_list,n - 1,t)

      Dict = {'4213' : ('STEM Center', 0),
    '4201' : ('Foundations Lab', 1),
   '4204' : ('CS Lab', 2),
    '4218' : ('Workshop Room', 3),
   '4205' : ('Tiled Room', 4),
       'out' :  ('Outside', 5),
   }

    sensor_list=[]

       [ sensor_list.append((key,Dict[key][0],Dict[key][1])) for key in Dict ] #Adding 
      values to a dictionary into a tuple using list comprehension

     print(sensor_list)


    print recursiveSort(sensor_list,len(sensor_list),0)

   print recursiveSort(sensor_list,len(sensor_list),1)

   print sensor_list
```